# Return Dates of Three Consecutive Values in a Row

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula

I have a data file and I need to return the dates of when the value (MaxT) is greater than or equal to 30 (>=30) for 3 consecutive days.

**Data File:**

```
Date, MaxT
1872-03-01,31
1872-03-02,29
1872-03-03,37
1872-03-04,40
1872-03-05,22
1872-03-06,9
1872-03-07,28
1872-03-08,31
1872-03-09,35
1872-03-10,37
1872-03-11,44
1872-03-12,29
1872-03-13,35
1872-03-14,48
1872-03-15,33
1872-03-16,31
1872-03-17,38
1872-03-18,31
1872-03-19,42
1872-03-20,20
1872-03-21,24
1872-03-22,31
```

I have attempted to figure this out using the following code but, I do not think I'm even in the ballpark...

**Attempted Code:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:B23>=30,ROW(B2:B23)),IF(B2:B23>=30,ROW(B2:B23)))=3))
```

Comment: Given the data above what would the output be and what would it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your data file consists of 2 columns `Date` and `Max T`. If they are delimited by commas, you need to split them to 2 different columns using `Text to columns` delimited by commas `,`.

The `Date` should be in `Column A` and `Max T` in `Column B`.

Enter the below formula in cell`C2` and drag down,

```
=IF(AND(B2>=30,B3>=30,B4>=30),"Consecutive Range","")
```

[image]

The starting of the consecutive range of values greater than 30 will be shown in the output as above. You could then use a filter of some other excel function like `Index-Match` to get the corresponding dates. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I got it to work, but I'm not entirely sure how you would make it work without separating the formula into multiple cells.

One potential solution would be to write some of the formulas into a sheet that's in the background, place the final part of the formula in the front sheet and have it reference the "hidden" bits of the formula.

First, I wrote the data in columns... "Date" in Column A, "MaxT" in Column B.

The first part of the formula is written in cell D2:

```
=IF(B2>=30,B2,"")
```

The next part of the formula is written in cell E2:

```
=COUNT(D2:D4)
```

The last part of the formula is written in cell F2:

```
=IF(E2=3,A2&","&A3&","&A4,"")
```

The result of this formula, in column F, there are 7 cells that have three dates written in them, separated by a comma.

Note that you can make any character or string of text separate the three displayed dates by replacing the commas that are in-between the ampersand, quote text:

(`&","&`) can become (`&"anything you want"&`)

From here, auto-fill the formulas to the relevant cells.

***EDIT:***

One way to shorten the code is to add the COUNT formula into the last IF statement like this:

```
=IF(COUNT(D2:D4)=3,A9&","&A10&","&A11,"")
```

I do still think that the first IF statement will need to be separate from the rest of the formula, though.

**EDIT #2**

Here is the code in one single cell:

```
=IF(AND(B2>=30,B3>=30,B4>=30), A2&","&A3&","&A4,"")
```

Which will display three dates that are located within Column A, current row & the next two rows below it.

This code still produces 7 lines of results with the data that you've provided.